# Thread-safe parallel sparse-sparse matrix multiplication with Eigen and OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp, sparse-matrix, eigen, rcpp

According to the [docs](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html), Eigen supports multi-threaded dense v. dense, or row-major sparse v. dense, but not sparse v. sparse matrix multiplications. In my application I have 2 sparse matrices and I want to multiply them in parallel, i.e. obtain `C = A * B` where `C` and `B` are column major.

**[Edit:]** Specific to my application I also know the sparsity pattern of all matrices in advance, and I need to perform such matrix multiplication many times (each time updating the non-zero values of `C` using the updated `A` and `B`). This leads me to think that there should be a thread-safe way to perform this operation in this case since the memory allocation of `C` is fixed **[end edit]**

Given that Eigen gives fast read/write on column blocks for column-major sparse matrices, I can perform the operation by subsetting `B` into column blocks (suppose `A`, `B` and `C` have all been initialized and are of the correct size):

```
  int nchunks = 7; 
  int chunksize = B.cols() / nchunks;

#pragma omp parallel for
  for(int i=0; i<nchunks; i++){
    if(i == nchunks-1){
      C.rightCols(B.cols() - (nchunks-1)*chunksize) = A * B.rightCols(B.cols() - (nchunks-1)*chunksize);
    } else {
      C.middleCols(i*chunksize, chunksize) = A * B.middleCols(i*chunksize, chunksize);
    }
  }
```

In my application, I have to perform `A.transpose() * S * A` thousands of times where `S` is symmetric positive definite, and I can split this operation into 2 steps each done in parallel. The result must be symmetric. By doing so I get a significant speedup.

To my non-expert eyes, there should be no issue because all threads share `C` but each operates on a different set of columns. In fact I expect my application to be extremely sensitive to even tiny issues because it needs to maintain symmetry after running 2 such sparse matrix multiplications.

However, this code works on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04, with R 3.6.1 linked to Intel MKL), but *not* on Windows (I've tried with both vanilla R 3.6.1 and MRO 3.5.3). My application fails in some cases on Windows due to a failed Cholesky, in turn caused by `C` not being created correctly, which I've traced to the above chunk of code. Simply removing OMP solves the issue, of course at the cost of performance.
I have not been able to reproduce this consistently on Windows: in isolation, the product works correctly. But it is definitely an OMP issue because removing the parallel clause solves the issue.

So what's going on?

Here's a working piece of code

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List spmat_mult(const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::RowMajor>& A,
                      const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>& B){

  int nchunks = 7;
  int chunksize = B.cols() / nchunks;

  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> Cs(A.rows(), B.cols());
  Cs = A * B;

  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  clog << "Standard "
       << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count()
       << "us.\n";

  Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> C(A.rows(), B.cols());
  C = Cs;

  start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
#pragma omp parallel for
  for(int i=0; i<nchunks; i++){
    if(i == nchunks-1){
      C.rightCols(B.cols() - (nchunks-1)*chunksize) = A * B.rightCols(B.cols() - (nchunks-1)*chunksize);
    } else {
      C.middleCols(i*chunksize, chunksize) = A * B.middleCols(i*chunksize, chunksize);
    }
  }

  end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  clog << "OMP "
       << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count()
       << "us.\n";

  return Rcpp::List::create(
    Rcpp::Named("Cs") = Cs,
    Rcpp::Named("C") = C
  );
}
```

and on R

```
  library(Matrix)

  set.seed(1)

  n <- 5000 # choose size
  A <- B <- matrix(0, ncol=n, nrow=n)

  nnz <- 250
  A_rows <- sample(1:n, nnz, replace=F)
  A_cols <- sample(1:n, nnz, replace=F)
  B_rows <- sample(1:n, nnz, replace=F)
  B_cols <- sample(1:n, nnz, replace=F)

  A[A_rows, A_cols] <- apply(A[A_rows, A_cols], 1:2, function(x) runif(1))
  B[B_rows, B_cols] <- apply(B[B_rows, B_cols], 1:2, function(x) runif(1))

  A <- as(A, "dgRMatrix")
  B <- as(B, "dgCMatrix")

  C <- spmat_mult(A, B)
```

Comment: As a debugging principle, for code like this I prefer to isolate it away from R first.  So I'd write a trivial `main()` doing what you want to do.  If that works, then it is R getting in the way, possibly by the RcppEigen constructors re-using R memory which is something you generally need to avoid -- see the RcppParallel vignettes for some more on this.

Comment: Hi Dirk, the issue appears within C, I only wrote this function (which seems to work) to post this question. Unfortunately I wasn't able to reproduce the issue in a simple example. In my application, I only write the matrices using the code above and removing `#pragma omp parallel` completely solves the issue.

Comment: Have you verified that Eigen allows parallel updates of the same sparse matrix (even if the columns are different)?

Comment: @MaxLanghof no, but I have zero issues on linux, so I'm assuming it does. Any glitch in creating `C` would be picked up later in my application because it must be symmetric whereas I'm filling it by column (therefore issues would immediately translate to non-symmetries in the result).
Most of the time it works on Windows, too (e.g. I havent managed to make the code I posted here fail). But not always, which is why I'm wondering whats going on.

Comment: In short, the problem is that writing to a `SparseMatrix` is not thread safe because it might involves global memory allocations and copies.

Comment: @ggael in my application, the sparse matrices are completely fixed in terms of which elements are nonzero. A, B (and C) always have their nonzero elements at the same locations. I preallocate memory for all of them and then use the code above to change the specific values. I understand that in general the product is not thread safe, but in my application I dont get how it would constitute an issue. Is there a way to make it work? and to reiterate, I havent encountered any issue on linux.

Comment: @mkln Ok, if your sparsity pattern is pre-set and remains fixed then it would be more reasonable to expect concurrent accesses to different columns/elements to be safe (still, please double-check). This would be a useful point to mention in the question :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce on my mac. Works fine with either gcc or clang.

Comment: You might still give a try to the tip of Eigen default branch that contains this [changeset](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/commits/70e55a287bfe/).

Comment: @ggael thanks, I think it's beyond my expertise for now (I use Eigen via Rcpp) and I also don't have issues with linux so I'll stick with it for now.